# Advice on where to import app.less in bootstrap 3.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

So I am getting started with bootstrap 3.0 and realized that there have been quite a few changes. I would like to add a `app.less` for my site specific customizations. I know that it should be added to `bootstrap.less`, but I would like some advice on where to add it! Do I have to make any other changes to for example `package.json` or `gruntfile.js` to be able to use the "standard" grunt commands, such as grunt and grunt watch?

Untouched Bootstrap.less

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.0.0
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";

// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "type.less";
@import "code.less";
@import "grid.less";

@import "tables.less";
@import "forms.less";
@import "buttons.less";

// Components: common
@import "component-animations.less";
@import "input-groups.less";
@import "dropdowns.less";
@import "list-group.less";
@import "panels.less";
@import "wells.less";
@import "close.less";

// Components: Nav
@import "navs.less";
@import "navbar.less";
@import "button-groups.less";
@import "breadcrumbs.less";
@import "pagination.less";
@import "pager.less";

// Components: Popovers
@import "modals.less";
@import "tooltip.less";
@import "popovers.less";

// Components: Misc
@import "alerts.less";
@import "thumbnails.less";
@import "media.less";
@import "labels.less";
@import "badges.less";
@import "progress-bars.less";
@import "accordion.less";
@import "carousel.less";
@import "jumbotron.less";

// Utility classes
@import "utilities.less"; // Has to be last to override when necessary
@import "responsive-utilities.less";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make an additional LESS file that calls both your custom file and Bootstrap's.

So within `mystyles.less` you will have

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
@import "app.less";
```

Then when there is a newer version of Bootstrap, you will just replace files, keeping your file untouched.